# Sonar xml schema validation rule causes ClassNotFoundException

Tags: xml, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube5.1

We are using the XML language Sonar plugin and have successfully added some custom XPath rules but when we activate a schema check rule we get a ClassNotFoundException:

```
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMImplementationSourceImpl
```

Initially we were using Sonar version 5.1.1 with version 1.3 of the XML language plugin installed on Ubuntu 14.04 using Oracle Java version "1.8.0_45" - we actually tried various 1.7 and 1.8 Javas. We tried running the analysis first using Sonar runner v2.4 and then using the Sonar ant task v2.3 and both gave the same error.

We found that there is a JIRA already raised about this: [SONARXML-3](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARXML-3) but it has been closed as "won't fix" because it could not be reproduced on SonarQube 4.5.4.

We did a clean install of Sonar 4.5.4 with version 1.3 of the XML language plugin onto a Windows machine and used a very simple test case.

After the install we did the following:

- Created a custom rule based on the "XML schemas should be valid" rule
- Left the schemas to the default "autodetect" and set filePattern to "**/*.html"
- Added "html" to the file suffixes setting of the XML plugin
- Activated the custom rule in the "Sonar Way" profile

When we ran sonar runner on a single html file we still got the same error.

I have looked in the XML plugin jar and there it contains xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar in its META-INF/lib which contains the class that it complains it can't find.

I am not sure what to try next. Have we missed a step when configuring the Sonar server or Sonar runner?

**EDITED TO ADD SIMPLE PROJECT INFO:**

A single file for analysis, Basic.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Title of document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    some content 
  </body>
</html>
```

sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=simple:schema-test
sonar.projectName=Schema Check Test
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=.
```

Output from sonar-runner:

```
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0_45 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Linux 3.13.0-57-generic amd64
INFO: Runner configuration file: /home/mike/SonarDev/sonar-runner-2.4/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: /home/mike/SonarDev/SimpleSchema/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "en_GB", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /home/mike/SonarDev/SimpleSchema/./.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.5.4
13:08:39.283 INFO  - Load global referentials...
13:08:39.765 INFO  - Load global referentials done: 488 ms
13:08:39.805 INFO  - User cache: /home/mike/.sonar/cache
13:08:39.837 INFO  - Install plugins
13:08:39.864 INFO  - Download sonar-core-plugin-4.5.4.jar
13:08:39.933 INFO  - Download sonar-email-notifications-plugin-4.5.4.jar
13:08:39.979 INFO  - Download sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.4.jar
13:08:40.258 INFO  - Download sonar-java-plugin-2.4.jar
13:08:40.328 INFO  - Download sonar-xml-plugin-1.3.jar
13:08:40.512 INFO  - Download sonar-cpd-plugin-4.5.4.jar
13:08:40.528 INFO  - Download sonar-design-plugin-4.5.4.jar
13:08:40.553 INFO  - Download sonar-dbcleaner-plugin-4.5.4.jar
13:08:40.577 INFO  - Download sonar-l10n-en-plugin-4.5.4.jar
13:08:40.683 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
13:08:40.713 INFO  - Download mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar
13:08:40.761 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar4?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
13:08:44.377 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
13:08:47.843 INFO  - Load project referentials...
13:08:48.430 INFO  - Load project referentials done: 587 ms
13:08:48.438 INFO  - Load project settings
13:08:49.256 INFO  - Loading technical debt model...
13:08:49.348 INFO  - Loading technical debt model done: 92 ms
13:08:49.372 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
13:08:49.988 INFO  - -------------  Scan Schema Check Test
13:08:50.018 INFO  - Load module settings
13:08:51.201 INFO  - Loading rules...
13:08:51.930 INFO  - Loading rules done: 725 ms
13:08:52.035 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
13:08:52.447 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-07-22)
13:08:52.475 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-06-22, analysis of 2015-07-22 12:56:55.0)
13:08:52.480 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
13:08:53.015 INFO  - Base dir: /home/mike/SonarDev/SimpleSchema/.
13:08:53.022 INFO  - Working dir: /home/mike/SonarDev/SimpleSchema/./.sonar
13:08:53.024 INFO  - Source paths: .
13:08:53.024 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_GB
13:08:53.024 INFO  - Index files
13:08:53.224 INFO  - 1 files indexed
13:08:53.370 INFO  - Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
13:08:53.422 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor...
13:08:53.464 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor done: 42 ms
13:08:53.466 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
13:08:53.504 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 38 ms
13:08:53.510 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
13:08:53.533 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 23 ms
13:08:53.539 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
13:08:53.592 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 53 ms
13:08:53.593 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor...
13:08:53.608 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor done: 15 ms
13:08:53.608 INFO  - Sensor XmlSensor...
13:08:54.071 ERROR - Could not analyze the file /home/mike/SonarDev/SimpleSchema/Basic.html
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMImplementationSourceImpl
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.schemas.SchemaResolver.createLSInput(SchemaResolver.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.schemas.SchemaResolver.resolveResource(SchemaResolver.java:269) ~[na:na]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.DOMEntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(DOMEntityResolverWrapper.java:117) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1079) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(XMLSchemaLoader.java:660) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchema(XSDHandler.java:2052) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1008) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:620) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:575) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:541) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:255) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.XmlSchemaCheck.createSchema(XmlSchemaCheck.java:146) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.XmlSchemaCheck.validate(XmlSchemaCheck.java:232) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.XmlSchemaCheck.autodetectSchemaAndValidate(XmlSchemaCheck.java:164) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.XmlSchemaCheck.validate(XmlSchemaCheck.java:222) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.XmlSchemaCheck.validate(XmlSchemaCheck.java:260) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.analyse(XmlSensor.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:233) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:221) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48) [sonar-runner-batch2088275009626652419.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMImplementationSourceImpl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance(DOMImplementationRegistry.java:182) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.schemas.SchemaResolver.createLSInput(SchemaResolver.java:115) ~[na:na]
        ... 51 common frames omitted
13:08:54.077 INFO  - Sensor XmlSensor done: 469 ms
13:08:54.079 INFO  - Sensor LineCountSensor...
13:08:54.110 INFO  - Sensor LineCountSensor done: 31 ms
13:08:54.112 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (wrapped)...
13:08:54.112 INFO  - DefaultCpdEngine is used for xml
13:08:54.114 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
13:08:54.148 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (wrapped) done: 36 ms
13:08:54.639 INFO  - Execute decorators...
13:08:55.155 INFO  - Store results in database
13:08:55.494 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/simple:schema-test
13:08:55.592 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
13:08:55.593 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
13:08:55.698 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
13:08:55.782 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2015-06-24 and 2015-07-21
13:08:55.793 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2014-07-23 and 2015-06-24
13:08:55.799 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2010-07-28 and 2014-07-23
13:08:55.809 INFO  - -> Delete data prior to: 2010-07-28
13:08:55.826 INFO  - -> Clean Schema Check Test [id=312]
13:08:55.860 INFO  - <- Clean snapshot 695
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 18.958s
Final Memory: 12M/118M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you please provide a project reproducer please ? A small project with 1 source file and its sonar-project.properties file with which we can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: @Linda I have added details of a project with a single source file and the output from sonar-runner to the original question.